# Mac build for TestFlight showing "Not available for testing"

Tags: xcode, cocoa, code-signing, appkit, xcodebuild

I am trying to publish build for beta testing on testflight but it shows "Not available for testing" - doesn't give any other explanation either.

I have tried adding `com.apple.developer.team-identifier` and `com.apple.application-identifier` to entitlements as suggested here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/689377 and some other Github discussions. This is an AppKit app build via Xcode and xcodebuild. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The change is right, just make sure any related extensions and targets in the bundle also have these values set in their entitlements file.